# What does "M'YY" mean in a researcher's short biography?

Tags: publications

I just encountered this in a short author bio at the end of a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1167351) from 2003:

[image]

What does the "M'99" and "M'74" mean? It doesn't seem like it's the year of obtaining a doctorate. These researchers are from Australia, if that's any relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The critical fact that is alluded to in your question but not explicitly stated, is that the paper appears in *IEEE Transactions on Systems, Man, and Cybernetics, Part B (Cybernetics).* It is common in IEEE publications to indicate whether an author is a member of the IEEE and if so, to include the year in which they joined the Institute. The purpose is to highlight their long-term association with the organization and (at least indirectly) suggest that the person has had a sustained commitment to the fields of electrical and electronic engineering.

Comment: Good answer.  I could imagine seeing "M'74" in some other publication, where it would mean something associated with *that* publication or the organization that publishes it.

Comment: Beat me to it. To add some detail, SM = Student Member, M = Member, S = Senior Member, F = Fellow, and LM = Life Member. Not sure when they stopped using that format (would require a review by year of articles), but they now are more explicit and use "(Member, IEEE)" or the other variations, and omit the year.

Comment: Further, the change started in 2020 (for one IEEE Transaction journal I looked at). And there is now the category of Graduate Student Member apparently as well.